# Response.Redirect() will not redirect on Internet Explorer

Tags: c#-2.0

I am using

```
Response.Redirect("someurl",true);
```

in the page_preInit event to redirect all the requests that come to a page. It works fine on Firexox, but if i access the page from internet explorer 7/8, it says page can not be found and will not redirect to new URL.

Any idea why this happens??

Update:

I tried giving a radom URL in the redirect such as google.com and it works fine. Actually the URL I am trying to redirect is not accessible on my machine, it is on another VPN. I guess IE will not change the URL on the addressbar if it can not access the URL. Firefox on the other hand changes the address on the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned on the Update, IE wont change the URL if it returns 404. Since i had no access to the URL i am redirecting, it was returning a 404. But firefox behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Response.Redirect contained within a try/catch block? This can cause issues with Redirection.

Comment: Ross, there are no try catch blocks. I got the solution

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue where Internet Explorer would not redirect using a standard Response.Redirect call. I also saw the same issue on certain Android devices on WIFI, but who worked correctly on cell service. Very strange.

The problem is with Microsoft's legacy redirect method in .NET. Certain network routers and older browsers handle the response codes differently. Here's the change to C# code that fixed it:

OLD CODE:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("www.mysite.com", true);
```

NEW CODE:

```
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Location", "www.mysite.com");
```